# How to improve performance of grouped DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, groupstyle

I am having some trouble with WPF when using [**GroupStyle**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.groupstyle?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) in a **[DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)**.

Loading the data itself is fine (about 2,500 rows). Also having **GroupDescriptions** on the **CollectionView** or calculating over the elements of the groups is absolutely fine in respect to performance.

But the visualisation is a complete nightmare.

I whittled it down to this. Once I define a **GroupStyle** like such in the **DataGrid**:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

It takes like 10 times as long to load the data and also uses 20 times the amount of RAM although there is actually no visual difference (Grid is yet empty)

This cannot be right. I must be doing something wrong. What am I doing that is causing the DataGrid to be so slow using the above **GroupStyle**?

Comment: You could try VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" inside the fatagrid tag. I think virtualization is still turned off when you group.

Comment: It does work, it is noticably faster to expand a group! But scrolling is less smooth in this case, which also isn't the case when not grouping. In my opinon it is better, but still not understandable why it cannot compete with ungrouped data.

Comment: Because grouping complicates virtualization. It has to work out more than the next n rows will fit in the remaining space

Comment: Im still not convinced, that this is the way its supposed to be. I dont know where else you could notice a delay to render 40 rows